# c++ declaring arrays as functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parallel-arrays

i'm facing some problems with the array, as I have my .h and .cpp files so do i declare them as per norm of how we usually declare a function?

pointtwod.h

```
class PointTwoD
{
    private:
        int xcord,ycord;
        float civIndex;
        LocationData locationdata;

    public:
            PointTwoD();

            PointTwoD(int, int, string, int, int, float, float, float);

        //set/mutator function
        void setxcord(int);
        void setycord(int);

        //get/accessor function
        int getxcord();
        int getycord();

        void storedata(int, int, float);

};
```

pointtwod.cpp

```
//declaring array
void PointTwoD::storedata(int xord[], int yord[], float civ[])
{
    int i=0;
    //int size = sizeof(xord)/sizeof(xord[0]);
    int size = 100;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        cout << "key in num for xord: " << endl;
        xord[i] = xcord;
        cout << "key in value for yord: " << endl;
        xord[i] = ycord;
        cout << "key in value for civ: " << endl;
        civ[i] = locationdata.getCivIndex();
    };
}
int main()
{
    PointTwoD pointtwod;
    pointtwod.storedata(xord[], yord[], civ[]);
}
```

when i compile the error message i get was even when i i put in int xord[]; in my PointTwoD.h file:

```
PointTwoDImp.cpp:99:6: error: prototype for 'void PointTwoD::storedata(int*,int*,float*) does not match any in class 'PointTwoD'

PointTwoD.h:48:8: error: candidate is: void PointTwoD::storedata(int, int, float)

PointTwoDImp.cpp: 135:22: error: 'xord' was not declared in this scope
PointTwoDImp.cpp: 135:27: expected primary-expression before ']' token
PointTwoDImp.cpp: 135:30: error: 'yord' was not declared in this scope
PointTwoDImp.cpp: 135:35: expected primary-expression before ']' token
PointTwoDImp.cpp: 135:38: error: 'civ' was not declared in this scope
PointTwoDImp.cpp: 135:42: expected primary-expression before ']' token
```

Comment: The error message looks pretty straight-forward to me.

Comment: Should be `void storedata(int*, int*, float*);`

Comment: in main you haven`t declared anything called xord[], yord[], or civ[] so no such variables exist in that scope, just as the error message says

Comment: so to remove the error message for 'civ' was not declared in this scope. I should put in float civ[]; in the private class of my pointtwod.h?

Answer (score 0):

```
PointTwoDImp.cpp:99:6: error: prototype for 'void PointTwoD::storedata(int*,int*,float*) does not match any in class 'PointTwoD'
```

This means the function does not match the prototype you declared in the header, which is this:

```
void storedata(int, int, float);
```

The declaration should be:

```
void storedata(int*, int*, float*);
```

Or:

```
void storedata(int xord[], int yord[], float civ[]);
```

The rest of the errors are because you haven't declared `xord[], yord[], or civ[]` in main, and you're passing them to the function.

So you need to declared the three arrays in `main` before passing them to the function.